# Swipe button like caller screen of Android

Tags: android, layout, android-canvas, android-view

Hi I want to create swipe button which is same as when we get call on android phone

Look at the below picture

[image]

I want to make same copy of this activity in that user can swipe those button

but i have no any example or any reference based on that i can detect would anybody help me how to do that

Comment: there's a plugin called Hammer.js that can make using swipe gestures easier: http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/ and there are others as well... look around for them, they're not hard to find